# How to show list view web part on all pages

Tags: 2013, web-part, page-layout, 2016

I have a list called "My List" which I am showing on a page in web part zone. This web part zone is inside a page layout like we normally do. I am applying XSL on this web part to display like they way I want.

Is it possible to show this web part by default in all pages? (on which we apply that page layout). I don't want to click on add a web part and then adding it and then applying XSL every time I create a new page.

How can I do this?